# xaml верхний и нижний отступы у button

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Делаю приложение для Windows Phone 8.1. Возникла проблемf контролом button.[image: button]

Как убрать отступы между реальными границами и телом кнопки сверху и снизу? Пробовал делать вот так

```
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0" />
```

не помогло.

Comment: Что вы называете реальными границами и телом?

Comment: "Реальной границей" я называю синюю тонкую рамку.

Comment: Окей, а откуда берётся такое необычное отображение кнопки?

Comment: Из style. Такие же отступы у абсолютно дефолтных кнопок. Есть подозрение что это где то в стандартной теме кнопки прописано, но я не уверен...

Comment: Окей, тогда дайте лучше скриншот без стиля. Если прописан дефолтный стиль, попробуйте установить насильно `Style="{x:Null}"`.

Comment: Нашел ответ вот здесь [Size of button in Windows Phone 8.1 App is not expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725005/size-of-button-in-windows-phone-8-1-app-is-not-expected)